# Programming mbed LPC1768 via ISP

Tags: isp, mbed

I'd like to experiment programming the mbed's LPC1768 dev board (https://os.mbed.com/platforms/mbed-LPC1768/) using ISP with FlashMagic.

Is this possible without requiring physical modification of the board?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use that particular software?  Typical MBED boards support a CMSIS-DAP interface (which your software along with many more mainstream choices supports) but it is unclear if that particular very old board does.  Perhaps you should stick with the built in programming method for that board and moved to an SWD solution when you go to a production prototype.   There are also other LPC1768 boards which expose the necessary signals you could try in the meantime to verify assumptions.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, could you suggest other such boards? I've struggled to find many still in production

Comment: Maybe the real question then is why you want to use such an old MCU for your project.   Interestingly, in a quick search one cheap source of LPC1768 boards seems to be knock-off 3d printer controllers implementing http://smoothieware.org/flashing-the-bootloader

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I didn't think the LPC1768 was particularly old. I'd think it'll be around for a while?

Comment: The chip may not be *discontinued* soon, but you did notice that *development boards* for it seem to be.  It's about a decade old in a field that has seen a lot of growth - much of the explosion of the Cortex-M parts into popularity has happened since.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, Perhaps worth looking into LPC4000s? They seem to be the only other LPC chips with a QEI

Comment: Nevertheless, why upgrade to something more complex/higher spec than you need?

Comment: It's still unclear what's wrong with the MBED board's built-in programming method (which is by no means limited to MBED projects).  If you don't like that, and can't find another board with the chip then that would be a reason for finding something else.  Though as I was hinting at before, I did just find a $20 printer controller with it, in contrast to the $50 the barebones blueboard cost back in 2010...